# Formatting output with rank & spacing using ljust() and rjust()

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, ranking

Hi im having trouble converting a tupled list into a ranked format [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Pbx.png)

the original sorted list looks like:

```
[('the', 15549), ('and', 10119), ('of', 8838), ('to', 8278), ('i', 7446), ('a', 6778), ('in', 4757), ('was', 3497), ('it', 3427), ('he', 3367)]
```

which i have converted to:

```
the 15549
and 10119
of  8838
to  8278
i   7446
a   6778
in  4757
was 3497
it  3427
he  3367
```

However im unsure how to created a numbered ranking for the list nor the proper formatting for ljust() and rjust() to evenly space the rank, word, and number.

```
for (value,num) in sorted_list:
    #value = value.ljust(value, 5)
    #num = num.rjust(num, 5)

    print("{}\t{}".format(value,num))
```

Comment: What you meed by *created a numbered ranking for the list* ?

Comment: @Kasra 1. 2. 3. ... for each line depending on how many words are in the list like in the picture.

Comment: So whats your expected output? as seems your code return an acceptable output

Comment: @Kasra The output I currently have looks like http://i.imgur.com/cc1ircz.png im not sure how to use ljust() and rjust() to format the code and add an ordered ranking. I have tried the enumerate function for ranking however it seems to be causing my lines to merely repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.ljust(width[, fillchar])
```

Same for rjust.
Example:

```
str = "this is string example....wow!!!";

print str.ljust(50, '0');
    enter code here
```

result: this is string example....wow!!!000000000000000000

(Src: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_ljust.htm )

Also you can use rjust and ljust on string, you have to first convert your number to a string. ( str(num) )
With ljust and rjust you can leave out the '\t' from the print
Sorting:

```
list.sort(key = <function>)
```

for example if your list name is sorted_list:

```
sorted_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

so the sorting will use the number (index 1) in you pairs.
It will give you a descending order, if you need ascending, you can use:

`sorted_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)`

EDIT:

- Numbered rank:

You can use simply an iteration with and index element: i

```
for i in range(len(list)): ...
```

Or the enumerate function (which is more pythonish)

```
for (i, e) in enumerate(list):
```

Enumerate is 0 based, so you can modify this by the *start* argument.
End the result is:

```
l.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

for (i, (value,num)) in enumerate(l, start = 1):
    value = value.ljust(5)
    num = str(num).rjust(5)

    print("{}.\t{}{}".format(value,num))
```

Other format style you may use:

```
print("{}.\t{:<8}{:>8}".format(i,value,num))
```

With this, you don't have to use ljust and rjust. It's do the same, but your data is unmodified. - Also it does not convert the number and you don't have to create new variables.

Comment: brillant thank you, seems I was missing converting num to string. Just now need to create numbered rank.